# xamarin form : how to add dynamic textbox and save mutiple in database

Tags: xamarin.forms, asp.net-web-api2

i need to know how i can create dynamic textbox or add textbox in listview for example i have one textbox and button when i click on button another textbox should add down below or how i can add some thing in textbox and display in listview. Here is one image down below for example, i need something similar to be done.
[image]

2nd thing thing i need to know how i can save a listview data in database (sql server) using webapi. I could save data from xamarin but with single textbox, i need to know how i can save listview data save in table at same time.

Comment: You can use ViewCell and   add this ViewCell to the ItemTemplate of the ListView.And add subview(textbox) in ViewCell .For more detail you can access to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/list-view/